# Phonegap touch plugin execution UIThread

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am making a custom plugin for Phonegap. Within Android all works fine. The `exec` function executes the Phonegap Java code imediately. This is all fine because than my data is send realtime to my computer.

But when I have the exact same JS and created this plugin in IOS the `exec` plugin function in IOS native code is only executed when I touchend or stop moving my finger. So when I touchstart and start moving my finger, I can see that the `exec` function is called by adding `console.log` before the plugin call. But when I set a breakpoint in my plugin IOS code it is called when I stop moving my finger or touchend. When I stop moving my finger all the calls to the native code gets executed after each other.

Which means that while I am using the UIThread the plugin IOS code is not called. Are there any solutions for this? So the Phonegap RunInBackground function is no use since we never get the while moving my finger. Als using a JS Worker does not seem to help.

Javascript:

```
WifiInfo.prototype.setColor = function(mac, groupnr, angle, success, fail) {
    console.log("START SENDING"); // This does work
    cordova.exec(success, fail, 'WifiInfoPlugin', "send", ["setColor", angle == -1 ? angle : Device.colorAngleToDevice(angle), mac, groupnr ] );
};
```

IOS:

```
- (void)send:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    // Code here. Made a breakpoint. The console.log above is executed. But the breakpoint
    // over here is not called. It is called when I stop moving my finger
    // or touchend
}
```

Comment: maybe some code can help

Comment: Added some code. But don't think that will help fix the issue. Since it has something todo with runnig on the UIThread I expect.

Comment: The code I want to see is where you call the WifiInfo.prototype.setColor. But if you think the problem is with the UIThread, you can try to run the plugin code on a background thread: [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
        //Your plugin code here
    }];

Comment: Tried that. But the breakpoint in the IOS code never gets to the `self.commandDelegate` because the IOS code is called when I stop moving my finger.

Comment: I just tried a demo plugin called with ontouchmove event and returned correctly while I was moving my finger

Comment: I am updating my background color and a radius, and some more colors. And still not calling my Plugin "real time". I am using this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/mattfarina/farbtastic